# Making an api call to render a button and need to be able to manipulate the button: for example be able to turn the font color red

Tags: html, css, api-design

This code below makes an API call to Bread and renders the bread button in the form. The documentation is as follows http://developers.getbread.com/#overview. I am trying to manipulate the button font to turn the color red. I also need to provide different shipping options and choices upon clicking the button. Currently the button has an error of: "button.js:353 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to 
                             execute 'postMessage' on 'Window': Invalid target 
                             origin 'null' in a call to 'postMessage'.
                             at Object.m.sendMessageToParent (https://checkout-
                     sandbox.getbread.com/button.js?8de5009c21d5d0c971ad:1:41964)
                             at ...please ask if you need this link have exceeded amount I can post on one question"

Checkout below:

DBPOWER T20 1500 Lumens LCD Mini Projector, Multimedia Home Theater Video Projector Support 1080P HDMI USB SD Card VGA AV for Home Cinema TV Laptop Game iPhone Andriod Smartphone with Free HDMI Cable

```
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "./Bread.css" />
<img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/411utAweOUL._SL500_AC_SS350_.jpg" alt="Projector"/>
<p> Sale: $100 </p>

<!-- Include our button within a form for seamless integration -->
<form id="checkout-form" action="checkout" method="post">
  <!-- Note that you must pass a div element -->
  <div id="bread-checkout-btn" data-bread-default-size=true></div>
</form>

    <!-- Load the bread.js script (this can be here or usually in the head) -->
<script src="https://checkout-sandbox.getbread.com/bread.js" data-api-key="7101ea30-8ae3-47ab-a8bd-235860d36f3e"></script>

<!-- Create the `opts` object -->
<script type='text/javascript'>
  var cart = {products:  [{name: "Mini Projector", price: 100, sku: "0349j0394fj", imageUrl: "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/411utAweOUL._SL500_AC_SS350_.jpg", detailUrl: "https://www.amazon.com/DBPOWER-T20-Projector-Multimedia-Smartphone/dp/B01LZRUY6Q/ref=pd_lpo_vtph_229_bs_tr_img_1?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=ZMXPZ67AYGWG50ACJX57", quantity: 1}]}
  var items = [];
  // We will assume you have a `cart` object which has `products`
  // the shopper has chosen.
  cart.products.forEach(function (p) {
    items.push(
      {
        name: p.name,                       // required
        price: parseInt( (p.price * 100) ), // required (value in cents USD)
        sku: p.sku,                         // required
        imageUrl: p.imgUrl,                 // optional
        detailUrl: p.detailUrl,             // required
        quantity: parseInt(p.quantity)      // required
      }
    );
  });

  // If you have their shipping address already, you can pass it to us
  // so they do not have to fill it out again.
  var shippingContact = {
    firstName: 'Kyle',
    lastName: 'McDonald',
    address:  '225 East 95th street',
    address2: '1D',
    zip:      '24321',
    phone:    '9144177703',
    city:     'Charleston',
    state:    'SC',
  };

  // Likewise, if you have the billing contact, you can pass it in to us
  // so they do not have to.
  var billingContact = {
    email:      'kyle2mcdonald@gmail.com',
    firstName:  'Kyle',
    lastName:   'McDonald',
    address:    '225 East 95th street',
    address2:   'Apt. 1D',
    zip:        '24321',
    phone:     '9144177703',
    city:       'Charleston', 
    state:      'SC', 
  };

  // var billingContact = {
  //   email:      'jane.doe@geocities.com',
  //   firstName:  'Jane',
  //   lastName:   'Doe',
  //   address:    '123 Test St.',
  //   address2:   'Apt. 4',
  //   zip:        '11238',
  //   phone:     '5555555555',
  // };

  // Below, we will build the required opts object.
  var opts = {
    buttonId: 'bread-checkout-btn',
    items: items,
    // Optional Array of Shipping Options
    shippingOptions: [
      {
        type: '2-day shipping',
        typeId: 'GS_001',
        cost: 1350,
      }
    ],
    tax: 0, // optional
    shippingContact: shippingContact,
    billingContact: billingContact
  };

  // We will assume your `cart` object has the `total`
  // dollar amount of products in the cart.
  if (cart.total > 2000) {
    // Use a non-default Targeted Financing Program for carts over $2000
    opts.financingProgramId = '0000000-aaaa-bbbb-cccc-ddddddddddd';
  }

  // Lastly, call `checkout` with `opts` as the argument.
  bread.checkout(opts);
</script>
```

Comment: Hey Kyle, sorry to hear that you had difficulty getting Bread set up, and that I didn't see this question sooner. I'm sure you've since figured this out, but if you need any other help with your Bread integration, give our Merchant Success team a call at (844) 992-7323,  https://www.getbread.com/contact/

Answer (score 0):

The option you are looking for is called `customCSS`, and takes a string of CSS rules and applies them to the button. Put that string on your `opts` object and pass that to your call to `bread.checkout(opts)`.

Docs for button options: https://docs.getbread.com/docs/manual-integration/bread-checkout/#targeted-financing

Docs for custom button styles: https://docs.getbread.com/docs/manual-integration/button-styling/

source: I am a developer at Bread

Also, for the record you can ignore that error, it is not related or problematic.